# Outlook don't show ics as event in mail

Tags: email, events, outlook, icalendar

This code sends a message to an Outlook account with an ics archive attached, but Outlook does not recognize it as an event and does not show it in the preview.
With Gmail there are no problems. It shows the preview goodly, but Outlook seems to be incompatible. I'm using ical4j libary version 3.0.6. 
Could someone help me find the problem? Thanks

```
        final String username = "example@gmail.com";
        final String password = "pass";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        try {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

            // Define message
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.addHeaderLine("method=REQUEST");
            message.addHeaderLine("charset=UTF-8");
            message.addHeaderLine("component=VEVENT");
            message.addHeaderLine("Content-Type: multipart/alternative");


            MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
            mimeMessage.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding:", "quoted-printable");
            mimeMessage.setHeader("Content-Type:", "multipart/alternative");

            Address address = new InternetAddress("example@gmail.com");
            mimeMessage.setFrom(address);
            message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, "example@outlook.es");
            message.setSubject("Outlook Meeting Request Using JavaMail");

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            StringBuffer buffer = sb.append("BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n" +
                    "PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 9.0 
                     MIMEDIR//EN\n" +
                    "VERSION:2.0\n" +
                    "METHOD:REQUEST\n" +
                    "TZID:Romance Standard Time\n"+
                    /*"BEGIN:STANDARD\n"+
                    "DTSTART:16010101T030000\n"+
                    "TZOFFSETFROM:+0200\n"+
                    "TZOFFSETTO:+0100\n"+
                    "RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;
                     INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10\n"+
                    "END:STANDARD\n"+*/
                    "BEGIN:DAYLIGHT\n"+
                    "DTSTART:16010101T020000\n"+
                    "TZOFFSETFROM:+0100\n"+
                    "TZOFFSETTO:+0200\n"+
                    "RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;
                     INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3\n"+
                    "END:DAYLIGHT\n"+
                    "BEGIN:VEVENT\n" +
                    "ATTENDEE;EXPECT=REQUIRE;
                     RSVP=YES:MAILTO:example1@outlook.es\n" +
                    "ORGANIZER:MAILTO:example@gmail.com\n" +
                    "DTSTART:20051208T053000Z\n" +
                    "DTEND:20051208T060000Z\n" +
                    "LOCATION:Conference room\n" +
                    "TRANSP:1\n" +
                    "SEQUENCE:0\n" +
                    "LOCATION;LANGUAGE=es-ES:\n"+
                    "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:0\n"+
                    "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:2117356856\n"+
                    "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE\n"+
                    "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY\n"+
                    "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE\n"+
                    "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1\n"+
                    "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0\n"+
                    "X-MICROSOFT-DONOTFORWARDMEETING:FALSE\n"+
                    "X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE\n"+
                    "X-MICROSOFT-LOCATIONS:[]\n"+
                    "UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008000000000"+
                     02FF466CE3AC5010000000000000000100\n" +
                    " 000004377FE5C37984842BF9440448399EB02\n" +
                    "DTSTAMP:20051206T120102Z\n" +
                    "CATEGORIES:Meeting\n" +
                    "DESCRIPTION:This the description of the meeting\n" +
                    "SUMMARY:Test meeting request\n" +
                    "PRIORITY:5\n" +
                    "CLASS:PUBLIC\n" +
                    "BEGIN:AALARM\n" +
                    "TRIGGER:PT1440M\n" +
                    "ACTION:DISPLAY\n" +
                    "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\n" +
                    "END:AALARM\n" +
                    "END:VEVENT\n" +
                    "END:VCALENDAR");

            // Create the message part
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            // Fill the message
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("
            Content-Class", "urn:content-  classes:calendarmessage");
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "calendar_message");
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "inline");
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("filename", "prueba.ics");
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(
                    new ByteArrayDataSource(buffer.toString(), 
            "text/calendar")));// very important

            // Create a Multipart
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            // Add part one
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Put parts in message
            message.setContent(multipart);

            // send message
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException me) {
            me.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
CONTENT-TYPE:text/calendar;
```